# How do I build pysvn on Windows32?

Tags: python, windows, pysvn

I'm trying to build PySVN from source on my Windows 7 PC. It's running 64bit Windows, but for various reasons I need to compile it so that it works on 32bit Python. That's what we run on a lot of our automation servers.

I've downloaded the PySvn extensions source, I've got Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition installed. I've tried to  a batch to automate the process, it looks like this:

```
set PROJECT_DIR=%~dp0
set SRC_DIR=%PROJECT_DIR%pysvn-1.7.8

cd %SRC_DIR%\Builder

set SVN_VER_MAJ_MIN=1.8
call builder_custom_init.cmd

cd %SRC_DIR%\Source
python setup.py configure --platform=win32
```

When I get to the last line I get the error message:

```
Info: Configure for python 2.7.6 in exec_prefix c:\python27
('Error:', 'cannot find PyCXX include CXX/Version.hxx - use --pycxx-dir')
```

My python - include directory does not contain a file called Version.hxx. Where do I get this file, how do I fix this bug?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Did you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to install PYCXX by hand - it installs a Version.hxx under the Include folder on windows.

The source for PYCXX is here: http://cxx.sourceforge.net/

Another way is to point the C/L parameter --pycxx-dir at the Import folder under the pysvn root where the corresponding version of PYCXX for the version of pysvn is kept.

(On top of this you will have to build the subversion libraries on windows.)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)